# Angular Meteor $reactive vs getReactively

Tags: javascript, angularjs, meteor, reactive-programming, angular-meteor

I'm learning Angular Meteor and I have a question:

**What is the difference between using $reactive and getReactively?**

If you take a look at the API reference you get this for $reactive (http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/reactive):

> A service that takes care of the reactivity of your Meteor data, and updates your AngularJS code.
>
> This service wraps context (can be used with this or $scope) - so you can use it with any context as you wish

And this for getReactively (http://www.angular-meteor.com/api/1.3.2/get-reactively):

> Use this method to get a context variable and watch it reactively, so each change of this variable causes the dependents (autorun, helper functions and subscriptions) to run again.
>
> The getReactively method is part of the ReactiveContext, and available on every context and $scope.

As far as I could understand $reactive will make everything reactive ('this', '$scope' and son on as long as you apply it to them) and getReactively will make only that particular variable, or object reactive.

So if I make this:

```
    controller: function ($scope, $reactive) {
        var vm = $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        vm.sort = {
            name: 1
        };

        this.helpers({
            parties: () => {          
                return Parties.find({}, { sort : vm.sort });
            }
        });

        this.subscribe('parties', () => {
            return [{
                sort: vm.sort
               },
               this.getReactively('searchText')
            ]
        });
    });
```

Why don't I get the same result as if I was doing this:

```
    controller: function ($scope, $reactive) {
        var vm = $reactive(this).attach($scope);
        vm.sort = {
            name: 1
        };

        this.helpers({
            parties: () => {          
                return Parties.find({}, { sort : this.getReactively('sort') });
            }
        });

        this.subscribe('parties', () => {
            return [{
                sort: this.getReactively('sort')
               },
               this.getReactively('searchText')
            ]
        });
    });
```

If $reactive takes care of reactivity I was expecting to see anything inside this and $scope to be reactive and, like in getReactively, whenever something is changed, to cause its dependents to run again.

So: what am I missing?

Comment: I myself am still trying to get my head around this but from what I understand so far the helpers constructor does not do a deep watch of the object passed to it. In other words unless you use getReactively you will not know of the deeper properties changing. Wish I knew for sure but there is so much conflicting documentation because of the rapid changing implementation

Comment: See this dicussion https://github.com/Urigo/angular-meteor/issues/955

Comment: That's very clarifying. Thanks a lot, @Precastic!